# Как добавить элемент в структуру

Tags: golang

есть структура

```
tAlbum struct  {
        artist string
        genre string
        title string
        year uint16
        amount byte
    }
```

есть переменная genre мне надо добавить её в структуру

```
var a = []tAulbum{}

a.append(genre: genre)
```

но так не работает

Comment: Вам нужно в **срез** структур добавить новую структуру с этим жанром или в уже имеющуюся **одну** структуру его проставить?

Comment: 2-e @Ainar-G =-

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так:

```golang
a := album{}
a.genre = genre
```

Или так:

```golang
a := album{
	genre: genre,
}
```

(Приставки для типов в го не приняты.)